# Power set of natural set is greater than natural set but what concept am I missing to visualize it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we put all the subsets of ℕ in a "tree" it seems to me that we can pair them with P(ℕ) meaning they have the same cardinality. In my picture, "N" means no, "Y" means yes, and let say every finite sequence is follow by infinite N's. For instances, "N" = "N N N ..." and "N Y N Y" = "N Y N Y N N N N... "

Now in the picture we can list the "tree" from top to bottom and left to right like this:

N, Y, NN, NY, YN, YY, NNN, NNY, NYN, NYY, YNN, YNY, YYN, YYY,...

This equal to {}, {1}, {}, {2}, {1}, {1,2}, {}, {3}, {2}, {2,3}, {1}, {1,3}, {1,2}, {1,2,3},...

Now we take out all the duplicate sets and get all the subsets of ℕ in an order:

{1, 2, 3, 4,...}

{{}, {1}, {2}, {1,2}, {3}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {1,2,3},..}

It looks like there is a bijection so |P(ℕ)| = |ℕ|. What am I missing?

Let me know if I need to clarify something more. [image]

Comment: What you have in fact shown is that there as many natural numbers as there are *finite* subsets of the natural numbers.

Comment: Where would, say, the set of odd numbers appear on this tree?

Comment: Noah, the set of odd numbers would be YNYNYNY...

Comment: How come it never reaches to infinite subsets?

Comment: @randomdude because your strings are always eventually all N’s, then you can only have finitely many Y’s. that is to say, there is some index M in your string such that at any point after it, it’s just N. this means there can be at most M Y’s.

Comment: I think the main challenge for actually visualizing the powerset of $\mathbb N$ is the fact that infinity is not very intuitive. Are you aware of the [Grand Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) paradox? This holds for $\mathbb N$, which in some sense is the simplest, smallest infinite set. But what you are trying to visualize are infinite sequences of N and Y, so that is bound to add more counter-intuitive things to the mix. For example try to think which infinite sequence follows immediately after $NYNYNY.....$ in lexicographic order.